# Why did the federal police come to arrest Quaid and why was the operator at Recall killed?

Tags: plot-explanation, total-recall-2012

Why did the federal police come to arrest Quaid suddenly? They should not have arrested him because everything was going according to their plan. First I thought, the man in the Recall might have pressed an alarm, but that does not fit well as they tried to kill each other(the man of the Rekall and the police). So why and how did the police know to come and arrest Quaid?

Also why did the police kill the man and why was the man shooting at them?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we're talking about the 2012 Total Recall. The SWAT team arrives because Lori---constantly surveilling Quaid---knew that Quaid participating in Rekall would "pop his memory cap" and reveal that his implanted memories were fakes.  Remember that Lori has absolutely no idea why she's handling Quaid or what his purpose is.

So, yeah, while Quaid going rogue and attempting to contact the resistance was Cohagen's (and, I guess, pre-memory screwery Quaid's) plan, Lori had no knowledge of any of this.  So she sicked the SWAT team on Rekall.  One assumes, to stop the memory implanting procedure before it happens.

Comment: And, remember, owing to Phillip K Dick's original intent, it's entirely possible none of that actually happened and that the "SWAT team" burst in because that's how the super secret agent memory experience was programmed.